# Neo4J 2.0.0 - IndexDefinition for relationship indices?

Tags: neo4j

Neo4J 2.0 provides new API for indexing and finding nodes (`Schema`, `IndexDefinition`, `Label` and `findNodesByLabelAndProperty`).

But what about relationships? Relationship indexing was one of the features of so called "legacy indexing". Are there any plans for relationship schema? Will relationship indices become obsolete and deprecated one day? Will we see `findRelationshipsByTypeAndProperty` in new API? Do I need to use both "legacy" and "new" indexing to get the full power of Neo4J? It's strange.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have a tree with a lot of leaves and would like to get all leaves that are related to an node with an specific property which is currently very slow. I think i have to create an relationship index ... how can i do that ?? can't find a way, autoindexing does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.0 there will be schema indexes on nodes but not on relationships. The only way to index relationships is by legacy or auto indexes. In most projects I've seen, only nodes were indexed but not relationships.

Can you clarify your use case with respect to relationship indexing?

Comment: In my case, I'm doing an aggregate query to return `nodes` by the ordered sum of a `relationship` property and subsequently sorted by that result. The query takes quite long to execute. So my first thought was an index on the relationship property to speed up the query...